# Double-Pendulum Equation Bug

Tags: c++, graphics, physics, raylib

I have been making a double-pendulum simulator in C++ using Raylib and I have finished everything other than correctly implementing the equations. When doing so, however, no matter what I try, I can't seem to figure out why my implementation of the equations is not working.   Most likely I am missing something fundamental but it's so hectic as is that it's difficult for me to understand. How would I implement these equations successfully? For reference:

Angular acceleration for pendulum 1 is angularA1

Angular acceleration for pendulum 2 is angularA2

I split the numerators in the equations into parts because it's simply too hard to keep track of it on one line. The problem is in main.cpp and the file generator is completely separate from the pendulum.

pendulum.h:

```
#ifndef DOUBLE_PENDULUM_SIM_PENDULUM_H
#define DOUBLE_PENDULUM_SIM_PENDULUM_H


class pendulum {
public:

    //Pendulum length
    float pLength{};

    //Pendulum mass
    float pMass{};

    //Pendulum's x component
    float x{};

    //Pendulum's y component
    float y{};

    //Pendulum's angular displacement relative to its origin
    float pAngle{};


public:

    void setAngularV(float angV);
    void setAngularA(float angA);

    [[nodiscard]] float getX() const ;
    [[nodiscard]] float getY() const ;

    [[nodiscard]] float getAngle() const ;
    [[nodiscard]] float getMass() const;
    [[nodiscard]] float getLength() const;

    void setX(float length, float angle);
    void setY(float length, float angle);

    void setLength(float length);
    void setMass(float mass);
    void setAngle(float angle);

    //Default constructor
    pendulum();

    //Easier way to initialize pendulum
    pendulum(float length, float mass, float angle) : pLength(length), pMass(mass), pAngle(angle) {}

    //De-constructor to make sure pendulum objects are destroyed
    ~pendulum();


};

#endif //DOUBLE_PENDULUM_SIM_PENDULUM_H
```

pendulum.cpp:

```
#include "includes/pendulum.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <raylib.h>


void pendulum::setX(float length, float angle) {
    x = length * sin(angle);
}

void pendulum::setY(float length, float angle) {
    y = length * cos(angle);
}

float pendulum::getX() const {
    return x;
}

float pendulum::getY() const {
    return y;
}

void pendulum::setLength(float length) {
    pLength = length;
}

void pendulum::setMass(float mass) {
    pMass = mass;
}


float pendulum::getAngle() const {
    return pAngle;
}

pendulum::~pendulum() {
    std::cout << "\nPendulum destroyed" << std::endl;
}

void pendulum::setAngle(float angle) {
    pAngle = angle * DEG2RAD;
}

float pendulum::getMass() const {
    return pMass;
}

float pendulum::getLength() const {
    return pLength;
}

//Default constructor
pendulum::pendulum() = default;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "raylib.h"
#include "includes/pendulum.h"
#include "includes/GenerateFile.h"
#include <cmath>

void testPendulum();

GenerateFile generator;

pendulum pen1;
pendulum pen2;

//The universal constant for gravity, for these purposes however, it can be any value as long as it works
const float g = 1;

int main() {

    //Prompt to make the initial values themselves
    float uLength1, uLength2, uMass1, uMass2, uAngle1, uAngle2;

    //Recommendation: 100 200 for length, 20 25 for mass, 45 0 for angle
    try {

        std::cout << "Please choose the length of each pendulum, starting with Pendulum 1, then Pendulum 2. Each value provided can be up to 7 decimal digits, " << "\n" << "length MUST BE greater than 50 and less than 200" << "\n";
        std::cin >> uLength1 >> uLength2;
        std::cout << "Please choose the mass of each pendulum, starting with Pendulum 1, then Pendulum 2. Each value provided can be up to 7 decimal digits, " << "\n" << "mass MUST BE greater than 20 and less than 100" << "\n";
        std::cin >> uMass1 >> uMass2;
        std::cout << "Please choose the starting angle of each pendulum, starting with Pendulum 1, then Pendulum 2. Each value provided can be up to 7 decimal digits" << "\n";
        std::cin >> uAngle1 >> uAngle2;

    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    //Init angular acceleration and angular velocity for pendulums

    float angularV1 = 0;
    float angularV2 = 0;

    //Pendulum 1 settings
    pen1.setMass(uMass1);
    pen1.setLength(uLength1);
    pen1.setAngle(uAngle1);
    pen1.setX(pen1.pLength,pen1.getAngle());
    pen1.setY(pen1.pLength, pen1.getAngle());

    std::cout << "X coord: " << pen1.getX() << " Y coord: " << pen1.getY() << std::endl;

    //Pendulum 2 settings
    pen2.setMass(uMass2);
    pen2.setLength(uLength2);
    pen2.setAngle(uAngle2); //Can only set this once and cant anywhere else, why?
    pen2.setX( pen2.pLength,pen2.getAngle());
    pen2.setY( pen2.pLength,pen2.getAngle());
    pen2.x = pen1.getX() + pen2.getX();
    pen2.y = pen1.getY() + pen2.getY();

    std::cout << "X coord: " << pen2.getX() << " Y coord: " << pen2.getY() << std::endl;

    //Window settings
    const double screenWidth = 1440;
    const double screenHeight = 1080;

    Vector2 origin{(float) screenWidth/2,(float) screenHeight/3};

    InitWindow((int) screenWidth, (int) screenHeight, "Double-Pendulum-Sim");

    int frameCounter = 0;

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    //Set coords for pendulums
    float px1 = pen1.getX() + origin.x;
    float py1 = pen1.getY() + origin.y;

    float px2 = pen2.getX() + origin.x;
    float py2 = pen2.getY() + origin.y;

    //Load & start pathing
    RenderTexture2D target = LoadRenderTexture((int) screenWidth, (int) screenHeight);

    BeginTextureMode(target);
    ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
    EndTextureMode();

    /****Write data to a file*****/

    //Init new Values.txt file
    generator.file.open("Values.txt");

    if(!generator.file) {
        perror("Error finding or opening file");
    } else {
        std::cout << "File opened successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    generator.file << "Angle 1    | X_1         | Y_1         | Angle 2    | X_2         | Y_2         | Frame # " << std::endl;



    //Main while loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        Vector2 rod1{px1,py1};
        Vector2 rod2 {px2, py2};

        //Implement angular acceleration for first pendulum equations:
        float num1 = -g * (2 * pen1.getMass() + pen2.getMass()) * sin(pen1.getAngle());
        float num2 = -pen2.getMass() * g * sin(pen1.getAngle() - 2 * pen2.getAngle());
        float num3 = -2 * sin(pen1.getAngle() - pen2.getAngle()) * pen2.getMass();
        float num4 = pow(angularV2, 2) * pen2.getLength() + pow(angularV1,2) * pen1.getLength() * cos(pen1.getAngle() - pen2.getAngle());
        float den1 = pen1.getLength() * (2*pen1.getMass() + pen2.getMass() - pen2.getMass() * cos(2*pen1.getAngle() - 2 * pen2.getAngle()));

        float angularA1 = (num1 + num2 + num3*num4) / den1;

        //Angular acceleration for second pendulum:
         num1 = 2 * sin(pen1.getAngle() - pen2.getAngle());
         num2 = (pow(angularV1,2.0) * pen1.getLength() * (pen1.getMass() + pen2.getMass()));
         num3 = g * (pen1.getMass() + pen2.getMass()) * cos(pen1.getAngle());
         num4 = pow(angularV2,2.0) * pen2.getLength() * pen2.getMass() * cos(pen1.getAngle() - pen2.getAngle());
         den1 = pen2.getLength() * (2*pen1.getMass() + pen2.getMass() - pen2.getMass() * cos(2*pen1.getAngle() - 2*pen2.getAngle()));

        float angularA2 = (num1 * (num2 + num3 + num4)) / den1;


        /**------------------Update------------------*/

            frameCounter++;
            uAngle1 += angularV1;
            angularV1 += angularA1;
            pen1.setAngle(uAngle1); //Can only set this once and cant anywhere else, why?
            pen1.setX(pen1.pLength,pen1.getAngle());
            pen1.setY(pen1.pLength, pen1.getAngle());

            px1 = pen1.getX() + origin.x;
            py1 = pen1.getY() + origin.y;

            uAngle2 += angularV2;
            angularV2 += angularA2;
            pen2.setAngle(uAngle2); //Can only set this once and cant anywhere else, why?
            pen2.setX( pen2.pLength,pen2.getAngle());
            pen2.setY( pen2.pLength,pen2.getAngle());
            pen2.x = pen1.getX() + pen2.getX();
            pen2.y = pen1.getY() + pen2.getY();

            px2 = pen2.getX() + origin.x;
            py2 = pen2.getY() + origin.y;

            //Write data to file by first getting the values of the pendulums:
            generator.getData(std::to_string(frameCounter),std::to_string(uAngle1),std::to_string(px1),std::to_string(px2),std::to_string(uAngle2),std::to_string(px2),std::to_string(py2));

    /**---------------------------------Draw-Pendulums & Path---------------------------------- */

    BeginDrawing();


            BeginTextureMode(target);
            DrawCircleV(rod2, 2.0f, RED);
//            DrawPixelV(rod2, RED);
            EndTextureMode();

            DrawTextureRec(target.texture, (Rectangle){0,0, (float) target.texture.width, (float) -target.texture.height}, (Vector2){0,0}, WHITE);

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

            DrawFPS(100, 100);


            DrawLineEx(origin, rod1, 5.0f, BLACK);
            DrawCircle( px1,py1,pen1.pMass,BLACK);

            DrawLineEx(rod1, rod2, 5.0f, BLACK);
            DrawCircle(px2,py2,pen2.pMass,BLACK);

            std::cout << "Frame #: " <<  frameCounter << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Pendulum 1 Angle: " << uAngle1 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Pendulum 2 Angle: " << uAngle2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Pendulum 1 X & Y: " << pen1.getX() << " " << pen1.getY() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Pendulum 2 X & Y: " << pen2.getX() << " " << pen2.getY() << std::endl;

    EndDrawing();

    }

    CloseWindow();

    generator.file.close();

    return 0;
}

//Test function
void testPendulum() {

    try {
        pen1.setMass(20.0f);
        pen1.setLength(150.0f);
        pen1.setAngle(0.0f);
        pen1.setX(pen1.pLength,pen1.getAngle());
        pen1.setY(pen1.pLength, pen1.getAngle());

        std::cout << "X coord: " << pen1.getX() << " Y coord: " << pen1.getY() << std::endl;

        pen2.setMass(50.0f);
        pen2.setLength(150.0f);
        pen2.setAngle(0.0f);
        pen2.setX( pen2.pLength,pen2.getAngle());
        pen2.setY( pen2.pLength,pen2.getAngle());
        pen2.x = pen1.getX() + pen2.getX();
        pen2.y = pen1.getY() + pen2.getY();


        std::cout << "X coord: " << pen2.getX() << " Y coord: " << pen2.getY() << std::endl;

    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

}
```

These are the Double Pendulum Equations I'm trying to use:
[image]

Comment: I am using this equation: https://ibb.co/Drh165R

Comment: Before I go rooting through your code looking for anything and everything that might be wrong, can we focus a little bit?  How do you know something is wrong? What are the expected vs actual results?  Have you made any attempt to debug it?  _"not working"_ is never a sufficiently detailed description of a problem.

Comment: The equation image should be uploaded to imgur — not left on ibb.co where it could vanish at any time.  It is a complex equation!

Comment: @Wyck Whenever I run the program, you need to set a few variables before hand, the length of the first and second pendulum, the mass of each, and its starting angle of each. After doing so a window will open and display a double pendulum with the settings you provided. What should happen is what you should expect from a simulation like this which is simple chaos and unpredictable motion that I can by tracing its path. However what actually happens, is in the first 3 seconds or so its fine and then simply it discombobulates and the graphics go all over the place.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Will fix that thank you!

Comment: Imgur link: https://imgur.com/a/cbmA2Cb

Comment: In your pendulum.h, there is no definition for  `angularA` or `angularV`, yet in pendulum.cpp there is `angularA = angA;` How did this compile?

Comment: @Wyck I removed it because it was unnecessary, I apologize for the confusion ill edit the post

Comment: I find it weird given `uAngle1 += angularV1` that `uAngle1` appears to be in degrees but I suspect that your calculation for `angularV1` will produce a value in radians wont it?  Suspiciously, numerical integration usually applies `x += x0 + dx/dT * deltaT`.  (where T is the time period of one frame or simulation step)  And in your simulation, deltaT is missing, so it is implied to be 1.  That may be an exceptionally large value for deltaT (e.g., might be a full second worth of change per frame depending on your units.)

Comment: You're using forward Euler integration with delta-t of 1 and g of 1.  While there may well be other problems, it's likely these parameters make the integrator unstable. You'll need to study the math of numerical integration more carefully. Delta-t (the time step) ought be a parameter of integration so you can adjust it. Turn it way down so you can look for other kinds of errors.

Comment: As Gene and I have said, but in terms of code, we're expecting `uAngle1 += RAD2DEG * (angularV1 * deltaT)` and `angularV1 += angularA1 * deltaT` where `deltaT` is the time step of one frame (if the calculation produces acceleration in radians per second, then `deltaT` should be _seconds per frame_  = 1.0/60.0 or so) But I don't understand what units your equation is working in since g is simply 1 (mass_units * pixels per frame per frame? that's likely unreasonably high.)  Your comment that "it can be any value" is wrong.  You should reconcile simulation units and display units and time units.

Comment: @Wyck Yes you are absolutely correct and after implementing dt I had some really interesting results, initially speaking I just had g = 1 to see what would happen out of curiosity sake. After implementing dt the program no longer brakes it just looks like its in slow motion which is far better than it was. What I am working on now is reconciling simulation units and display units and time units as you have said (and Gene as well!)

Comment: I'm hesitant to write an answer that just says "check your units" *everywhere*.  But that's basically what needs to happen.

Comment: @Wyck and Gene I managed to fix it, thank you so much for your help! This was the first time I tried to simulate something related to physics so it was pretty fun to learn about Raylib and the complexities of simulating something like this.

Comment: There exist ways to compute the first-order system structurally close to the theoretical derivation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084922/transform-the-double-pendulum-differential-equations-into-a-first-order-system/2084996#2084996. Separating the double-pendulum model from the view-elements could also allow to use higher-order ODE integration methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, you've made no attempt to use sane units in your code.  You've mismatched degrees and radians in at least one spot too by doing `uAngle1 += angularV1`.  `uAngle1` is in degrees, but the `angularV1` should likely be produced in radians per second.

That brings in the missing aspect of *time* in your numerical integration.

Numerical integration typically works by assuming velocity is linear under short time intervals.

A typical numerical integration inner loop calculation looks like this:

```
acceleration = netForce / mass;
velocity += acceleration * timestep;
position += velocity * timestep;
```

Whereas you just do:

```
velocity += acceleration;
position += velocity;
```

...which is like using a timestep of 1.
**The timestep must be small**.  For simulations that make gradual changes, it may be sufficient to just use the frame interval (e.g.: use a timestep of 1/60th of a second for a 60 fps simulation).  Some simulations will actually subdivide the frame interval into a number of simulations steps  (e.g. you could perform 100 updates per frame, each with a very small timestep of ((1/60) / 100).

Whatever happens, you should reconcile your units.  Make sure your gravitational constant makes sense given the scale of your world.  `g = 1` is likely much too large.  (@Gene made an excellent comment to this effect.)  Also make sure your timesteps are reasonable.  An implicit timestep may be interpreted as a time interval of 1 second (instead of 1 frame) and your simulation may be running an additional 60 times faster than you expect.  All this leads to large values and numerical instability in the integration calculation, which depends on small changes.

- You're currently using a distance unit of *pixels*, but perhaps it makes more sense to use a unit of *meters* and then scale your objects to fit the screen with a sane camera and viewport calculation.
- You're currently using a time unit of *frames*, but perhaps it makes more sense to use a unit of *seconds* and make use of either the known frames-per-second rate of your simulation, or keep track of the actual elapsed time with a clock so that the simulation doesn't stutter if frames are dropped.
- You're mismatching degrees and radians.  It makes sense to use degrees when interacting with the user and radians in your physics calculations, but be careful not to mix them up during your calculations.